# JavaScript prevent function from firing when window is closed

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, onunload

I have a text field, ID="Text1", which fires a function, "validateField()" when the Text1 field loses focus (it also checks if the enter key was depressed "onkeydown")

example:

```
<input type=text ID="Text1" onkeydown="wasEnterKey(); " onblur="validateField()" >
```

The problem is that when a user closes the window, this event fires and I want to prevent that from happening.

I have tried to use window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload in the validatField function:

```
function validateField() 
{
 if (window.onbeforeunload) { 
    window.open('','_parent','');window.close(); return false;
                            } 
... (other actions follow)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload` is an event handler. You assign it a function that you want to be executed just before the page is unloaded; you cannot check if you're in the middle of unloading the way you seem to think you can.

Comment: To avoid events from firing try window.onbeforeunload = null

Comment: One way could be to use a setTimeout to exec the callback a bit later, so that if he closes the windows it won't be run. Not super clean. I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: An Enter key low in spirit, ah

Comment: Use delay before  doing anything onblur

Comment: Thanks to @3on and @Champ! I have worked out a solution based on your suggested course of aciton. I have to wait six more hours to post my solution, but will do so later so others can use it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to: @3on and @Champ!

Here is the solution I worked out, thought the actual code could be helpful to someone. Thanks again!

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function delayBlur()
{   setTimeout( validatePwd, 100);  }

function closenow()
    {   window.open('','_parent','');window.close(); return false;  }

function validateField() 
{
    var field1 = document.myForm.Text1.value;
    if (Text1 == '')
    {... (other actions follow)}
}
</SCRIPT>
<input type=Text ID="Text1" onkeydown="wasEnterKey(); " onblur="delayBlur()">
```

This allows the window to close when the user clicks the close button, as both 3on and Champ suggested. It also prevents the enter key from submitting the form. I detect the enter key and replace the keycode with a tab key. I experimented with setting the timeout lower than 100 and had sporadic problems, 100 has never failed though!